# HTML table without space between columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple table with two columns

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbbbbb</td>                                        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbbbbb</td>                                        
  </tr>
</table>

tr:hover {
    background: grey;
}
```

When I put the mouse pointer above the row, the background of the row changes to grey, but there is little space between the rows

[image]

How can I remove this little space to keep the whole row in grey?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your `cellspacing` and `cellpading` to zero on the table

Comment: `cellpadding`, not `cellpading`, extra `d`

Answer (score 2):

Use `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` in table tag, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/WQvjBx

set your `cell-spacing` to 0

for html5 just add this to your css

`border-collapse: collapse`

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```